# When insulating foundation walls in a crawlspace with two layers of EPS foam board, is including air gaps a good idea?

Tags: insulation, crawlspace, styrofoam

I'm planning on insulating my currently uninsulated 6-inch concrete foundation wall. This is zone 5, so code says R-15 is required. I can achieve that with 2 layers of [2" EPS foam board (nominal R7.7 per layer)](https://www.homedepot.com/p/R-Tech-2-in-x-4-ft-x-8-ft-R-7-7-Rigid-Foam-Insulation-310891/202532856). What I'm wondering is if I can (and should) do better by including dead air space (as mentioned in the [installation guide](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/9e/9e0913b9-f642-4641-bb95-dd5b6699b6ca.pdf), though not for this specific application), or if that will make something bad happen on a crawlspace wall. Water is not a huge problem here in Boise, ID, but it's just semi-arid and we do get rain/snow in the winter and spring.

Here's how the wall looks now, followed by 3 options I can think of. Spacers would be strips left over after cutting boards to size, and they could completely enclose the dead air space.
[image]

**Option 1: no air gaps**
[image]

**Option 2: air gap between boards**
[image]

**Option 3: air gap between boards, and between board and wall**
[image]

Also, I can't find a consistent answer on how far down the wall the insulation should go. All the way to the footer? Above-grade only?